# Dispatcher.Invoke with anonymous delegate works in Silverlight but not WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, begininvoke, anonymous-delegates

In Silverlight 4 I have a custom service class which has an asynchronous Completed event.  Inside the Completed event I take the returned data and invoke a populate method via something like this:

```
private void service_Completed(object sender, CompletedEventArgs args)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => populateInbox(args.Jobs));
}

private void populateInbox(List<JobViewModel> jobs)
{
    inbox.DataContext = jobs;
}
```

The `BeginInvoke` works in SL4, however when I ported it to WPF I get the following error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

I tried changing it to an in-line, anonymous, paramaterized delegate:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate(List<JobViewModel> jobs)
{
    inbox.DataContext = jobs;
});
```

However, that yields the same compile-time error.

Any idea how to get this to work in WPF? Refactoring to use the `BackgroundWorker` is not an option for me.

Comment: Why is "Dispatcher.Invoke" in the title and in the real question you ask about "Dispatcher.BeginInvoke"? It's not the same...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to specify an explicit delegate type. Just use an `Action`.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => populateInbox(args.Jobs));
```

You could, however, avoid having to close over the `args.Jobs` value like this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action((jobs) => populateInbox(jobs)), jobs);
```

This is because the single-parameter version of `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` has a different signature in Silverlight than in WPF. In Silverlight, it takes an `Action`, which allows the C# compiler to implicitly type your lambda as an `Action`. In WPF, it takes a `Delegate` (like its `Control.BeginInvoke` analog in Winforms), so the C# compiler has to have a delegate type explicitly specified.

Comment: I'm getting this error now:  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Delegate, params object[])'.

I separated it out into 2 lines to try and see what is causing the error.  var d = new Action(() => populateInbox(args.Jobs)); Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(d, args.Jobs);  Error happens on the 2nd line.

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { args.Jobs }); Does not work either.

Comment: @Edward: `Dispatcher` is not a static class. You'll have to call this function either within the context of a UI element that has a `Dispatcher` property, or you'll have to pass in the dispatcher as another argument.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I'm trying to use a WPF user control from within an Excel workbook project. The WPF user control is hosted in an ActionPane with an ElementHost.  The pane is instantiated in a Ribbon control which does not have a Dispatcher property. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In WPF and winforms you must cast it to a MethodInvoker first, otherwise you will get the error *Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type.*

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate(List<JobViewModel> jobs)
{
   inbox.DataContext = jobs;
});
```

For more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx